# About base in C#

Tags: c#, radix

```
namespace contest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B b = new B();
        }
    }

    class A {
        public A() {
            k();
        }
        private void k() {
            Console.WriteLine(base.GetType().Name);
        }        
    }

    class B : A {

    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why it outputs "B" instead of "Object", doesn't base.GetType() get A's parent object therefore the root Object?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because

```
base.GetType()
```

means "call the `GetType()` method of parent class", though you haven't overriden it. Thus `base.GetType()` as well as `this.GetType()` would always return class `B`

Comment: In fact `GetType` is not virtual so you can't override it.

Comment: do you mean that if a method foo() is not virtual or override ,then call base.foo() always equal to this.foo()?

Answer (score 0):

B implements/inherits from A, when you initialise B b = new B() it will just use guts of a and therefore return type of the B. Try using A b = new B(); this should return A. You need to override method and also define A as abstract.

Answer (score 0):

`GetType` is defined on `System.Object` and is not virtual. It provides the runtime type of the object from the metadata. Therefore, it doesn't matter where you call it (in a constructor or virtual method) or if you use `base` or `this` you are always calling the same method. You will always get the runtime type, except in the case of Nullable types where you will get the  underlying type. My guess is that this is due the special boxing behavior of nullables. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on identifying nullable types.